# Kuberenetes 1.24 | Containerd | Allow to run devices inside the container without the --privileged flag?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, filesystems, alpine-linux, containerd

recently we upgraded our Eks clusters (Aws Kubernetes service) to version 1.24.

One of our workloads at Kubernetes is a job which uses `volumeDevices` at his manifest the here is a job manifest example:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1 
kind: Job 
metadata: 
  name: test-vol-05ca32fbf6a015b50
spec: 
  template: 
    metadata: 
    spec:
      containers: 
      - env: 
        - name: AWS_STS_REGIONAL_ENDPOINTS 
          value: legacy 
        - name: DevicePath 
          value: /dev/xvdf 
        - name: DeviceRootPartitionMountPath 
          value: /data 
        image: ****.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/engeksserviceimageoutpostworkerrepository:1.59.76.8053
        securityContext: 
          capabilities:
            add:
            - SYS_ADMIN
           seccompProfile:
             localhostProfile: compute-analysis-scanning
             type: Localhost
        volumeDevices: 
        - devicePath: /dev/xvdf
          name: test-vol-05ca32fbf6a015b50
      restartPolicy: Never 
      volumes: 
      - name: test-vol-05ca32fbf6a015b50
        persistentVolumeClaim: 
          claimName: test-vol-05ca32fbf6a015b50
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 300
```

The attached device `/dev/xvdf` is a volume of remote machine which we need to scan and report about files, therefore the attached device partitioned and formatted with a filesystem type (ext4, ext3, xfs etc..) As part of the entry point at the container we are executing the following command:
`lsblk -fnr -o NAME,FSTYPE /dev/xvdf`

The expected result is a list of partitions names and there filesystem type if exist for example:

```
nvme2n1 
nvme2n1p1 ext4
nvme2n1p14 
nvme2n1p15 vfat
```

**But** the actual result goes as follows:

```
nvme1n1 
nvme1n1p1 
nvme1n1p14 
nvme1n1p15
```

By looking at `strace` output we saw the following error:

```
open("/dev/nvme1n1", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getuid()                                = 0
open("/dev/nvme1n1p14", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getuid()                                = 0
open("/dev/nvme1n1p1", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getuid()                                = 0
open("/dev/nvme1n1p15", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

We realized that the container root filesystem files masked at the paths `/dev & /sys` and we can unmask them if and only if the flag `--privileged` is set true at the job manifest, but we are looking for another least privileged solution (like docker has a flag called --device).

Is there any option to define k8s manifest that enables access to specific device?